# How to grab the onSubmit event for a form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to know how to grab the `onsubmit` event from a form to do some form validation, because I don't have access to it directly. (I am writing a Wordpress plugin for comments, so don't have direct access to the form tag or the submit button.)

I got so frustrated trying to do this for my plugin that I have written a Hello World version below. I want it to show the 'Hello World' alert when I load the page, and the "form submitted" alert when I click on the submit button. Instead, it shows both pop ups when the page loads.

Here is my code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <form action="#" method="post" id="commentform">

    <p><input type="text" name="author" id="author" size="22" tabindex="1" />
    <label for="author"><small>Name (required)</small></label></p>

    <p><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Submit Comment" />

    </form>

    <script type="text/JavaScript">
    <!--
    alert("Hello world");

    var formCheck = document.getElementById("commentform");

    formCheck.onSubmit = doMapping(); 

    function doMapping() {
        alert("form submitted");
        return false;
    }

    -->
    </script>     

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 14):

Change this:

```
formCheck.onSubmit = doMapping()
```

to this:

```
formCheck.onSubmit = doMapping
```

When you add parenthesis to the end of a function you execute that function.  When you assign a function (or pass it as a parameter to another function) you need to omit the parenthesis as that is the way to retrieve a function pointer in JavaScript.

---

**Edit:** You will also need to move the declaration of the `doMapping` function above the assignment of that function to the onsubmit event like this (good catch tvanfosson!):

```
function doMapping() {
        alert("form submitted");
        return false;
    }

formCheck.onSubmit = doMapping();
```

However if the `doMapping` function is not used elsewhere you can declare the `doMapping` function as an anonymous function like this:

```
formCheck.onSubmit = function() {
        alert("form submitted");
        return false;
    }
```

which seems a bit cleaner to me.

Comment: I think you'll also have to change the order since doMapping may need to be defined before you assign it as the onSubmit handler.

Answer (score 8):

Using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#commentform').submit( function() {
        alert('form submitted');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! Actually I solved it another way, using both Andrew's suggestion and the window.onload event - I think the problem was partly because the element hadn't actually loaded.

```
window.onload = function(){
    if (document.getElementById("commentform")){
        document.getElementById("commentform").onsubmit = doMapping;
    }
}

function doMapping(){
            alert("form submitted");
            return false;
}
```

Comment: Note thought that the onload event is fired after the whole page has been loaded. So should there be an image that takes long to load - usually something like google analytics your event handler will not be assinged before the user hits submit.